# failed to read artifact

Tags: java, spring, maven

i want add org.springframework.spring.web-mvc3.2.0.RELEASE dependency in my project . but when i add this dependency and save that , it show this error : 
[image]
and pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>fit</groupId>
  <artifactId>Example01</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Example01 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>Example01</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you lost the connection to Maven central half way during the transfer. The problem is that your artifacts could become out of sync with Maven cache. If your local Maven repository is relatively small I would suggest to delete entire repository folder under .m2 and try to rebuild again from the command line (mvn clean install)